# How to pair Galaxy watch 3 from my android app

Tags: android, bluetooth, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I want to pair Galaxy watch 3 to my android application.
When I try to pair Galaxy watch 3 from Bluetooth setting then I moved to Galaxy wearable app automatically for pairing. Same behavior I want to implement in my android app. My application will search the watch and as user will select it to pair then it should move to galaxy wear app for pairing.
Samsung health app is already using the desired behavior. any idea or suggestion, how to achieve it in my app.

Comment: Did you not find: https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch-develop/creating-your-first-app/native-companion/interact-device.html

Comment: @MorrisonChang i have seen this link and implemented the same but problem is when i am trying to pair the Watch from phone's Bt setting then Galaxy wear app is automatically open for pairing. same behavior i wants to implement in my app.

Comment: From my understanding initial pairing needs to be done via watch manufacturer phone app to provide conduit for data. Otherwise how else will `com.samsung.android.sdk.accessory.SAService` from https://developer.samsung.com/galaxy-watch-develop/creating-your-first-app/native-companion/use-accessory.html on non-Samsung phones communicate with their apps. Note the same situation exists for Android Wear watch OS where Google's app provides the channel. Manufacturer app allow for multiple third-party apps to communicate to watch.

Comment: @MorrisonChang I agree that initial pairing needs to be done via phone manufacturer app, same is doing by Samsung health app. Samsung health app is making a connection via Galaxy wear app. Samsung health is searching a watch and as user clicks on it then move to Galaxy Wear app and initiate pairing. same thing i want to implement in my app any idea how to achieve it?.

Comment: My guess is that the watch or the app is transmitting/listening for a bluetooth signal (ble advertiser id perhaps?) allowing the app to "know" there is a galaxy watch device available to fire off the intent to Galaxy Wear app to initiate pairing. Given that Samsung controls both sides, Samsung can change the detection protocol at any time.